# Angularjs routing OTHERWISE causes 404

Tags: angularjs, routes, http-status-code-404, route-provider

I have a single page application where I route to different pages based on url address, I would like to redirect to Homepage when user enters non existing page in the url, so I use otherwise statement, however it causes 404 error, here is my routing config.:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            redirectTo: '/products'        
        }).
        when('/products/:id?', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/products.html',
            controller: 'ProductsController'
        }).
        when('/orders/:id?', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/orders.html',
            controller: 'OrdersController'
        }).
        when('/auto', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/AutoComplete.html',
            controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

**EDIT:**

Changed it as suggested below buts till the same affect, when I type non existing page it goes to Error 404 instead of /products

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            redirectTo: '/products'        
        }).
        when('/products', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/products.html',
            controller: 'ProductsController'
        }).
        when('/products/:id?', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/products.html',
            controller: 'ProductsController'
        }).
        when('/orders/:id?', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/orders.html',
            controller: 'OrdersController'
        }).
        when('/auto', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/AutoComplete.html',
            controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: function () { return '/' } });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Comment: do you have a /products?

Comment: Try to remove redirectTo: '/products'

Comment: yes I have /products and it works just fine, but when i type non existing page that's when I have a problem, it comes back with 404 instead of redirecting to /products

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `when('/'...` and the otherwise as they essentially do the same thing.
The otherwise is a catchall to get anything that isn't matched so you don't need to route the '/' specifically.

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/products/:id?', ...).
  when('/orders/:id?', ...).
  when('/auto', ...).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/products'
  });
```

**EDIT** The problem is that redirecting to '/products' won't match '/products/:id'. You'll need to add another route like as follows:

```
when('/products', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/products.html',
    controller: 'ProductsController'
})
```

Comment: Tried it, same result.

Comment: I did as suggested, but it made no difference.(see above)

Comment: Can you recreate it in a plunkr? You can use the one on the angularjs site to start you off: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.19/docs/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView